# log4j2 Output not written to log file

Tags: java, xml, windows, log4j2

I am trying to use log4j2 for the first time. I have copied some configuration examples from various sites and none seem to generate output to the log files. Output to STDOUT/console works ok.

I can see from the console output that log4j2.xml file has been located.

Any ideas on how to get it to write to the log file.

I am using Java 8 and log4j 2.5 on Windows 7.

**Java source code**

```
package log4j2Demo;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class LogDemo {
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LogDemo.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.debug("Hello world - debug log");
        logger.info("Hello world - info log");
        logger.warn("Hello world - warn log");
        logger.error("Hello world - error log");
    }
}
```

**log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="file-log" fileName="${log-path}/log4j2demo-info.log"
filePattern="${log-path}/log4j2demo-info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="a.demo.of.log4j2" level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="file-log" level="info"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**Console Output**

```
2016-05-20 00:31:46,345 main DEBUG Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\demo\log4j2Demo\bin\log4j2.xml]
2016-05-20 00:31:46,350 main DEBUG Installed script engines
2016-05-20 00:31:46,705 main DEBUG Oracle Nashorn Version: 1.8.0_91, Language: ECMAScript, Threading: Not Thread Safe, Compile: true, Names: {nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript}
2016-05-20 00:31:46,706 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 97 plugins
2016-05-20 00:31:46,706 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
2016-05-20 00:31:46,710 main DEBUG No scheduled items
2016-05-20 00:31:46,711 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=property, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property].
2016-05-20 00:31:46,723 main DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 23 plugins
2016-05-20 00:31:46,731 main DEBUG createProperty(name="log-path", value="logs")
2016-05-20 00:31:46,731 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=properties, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.PropertiesPlugin].
2016-05-20 00:31:46,737 main DEBUG configureSubstitutor(={log-path=logs}, Configuration(C:\demo\log4j2Demo\bin\log4j2.xml))
2016-05-20 00:31:46,737 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 13 plugins
2016-05-20 00:31:46,738 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2016-05-20 00:31:46,745 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(C:\demo\log4j2Demo\bin\log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2016-05-20 00:31:46,745 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 38 plugins
2016-05-20 00:31:46,759 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy].
2016-05-20 00:31:46,761 main DEBUG createPolicy(interval="1", modulate="true")
2016-05-20 00:31:46,762 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=Policies, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy].
2016-05-20 00:31:46,762 main DEBUG createPolicy(={TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=true)})
2016-05-20 00:31:46,763 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender].
2016-05-20 00:31:46,764 main DEBUG createAppender(fileName="logs/log4j2demo-info.log", filePattern="logs/log4j2demo-info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log", append="null", name="file-log", bufferedIO="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", Policies(CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=true)])), Strategy=null, PatternLayout([%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n), Filter=null, ignoreExceptions="null", advertise="null", advertiseURI="null", Configuration(C:\demo\log4j2Demo\bin\log4j2.xml))
2016-05-20 00:31:46,774 main DEBUG Starting RollingFileManager logs/log4j2demo-info.log
2016-05-20 00:31:46,776 main DEBUG PluginManager 'FileConverter' found 2 plugins
2016-05-20 00:31:46,778 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2016-05-20 00:31:46,780 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(C:\demo\log4j2Demo\bin\log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2016-05-20 00:31:46,784 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
2016-05-20 00:31:46,785 main DEBUG Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
2016-05-20 00:31:46,786 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 38 plugins
2016-05-20 00:31:46,788 main DEBUG Jansi is not installed, cannot find org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2016-05-20 00:31:46,789 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false-2
2016-05-20 00:31:46,799 main DEBUG ConsoleAppender$Builder(PatternLayout([%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n), Filter=null, target="SYSTEM_OUT", name="console", follow="null", ignoreExceptions="null")
2016-05-20 00:31:46,800 main DEBUG Jansi is not installed, cannot find org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2016-05-20 00:31:46,800 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false
2016-05-20 00:31:46,800 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
2016-05-20 00:31:46,801 main DEBUG createAppenders(={file-log, console})
2016-05-20 00:31:46,801 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender-ref, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2016-05-20 00:31:46,802 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="file-log", level="INFO", Filter=null)
2016-05-20 00:31:46,802 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
2016-05-20 00:31:46,806 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="false", level="INFO", name="a.demo.of.log4j2", includeLocation="null", ={file-log}, ={}, Configuration(C:\demo\log4j2Demo\bin\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2016-05-20 00:31:46,808 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender-ref, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2016-05-20 00:31:46,809 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="console", level="null", Filter=null)
2016-05-20 00:31:46,809 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
2016-05-20 00:31:46,810 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="false", level="INFO", includeLocation="null", ={console}, ={}, Configuration(C:\demo\log4j2Demo\bin\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2016-05-20 00:31:46,810 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
2016-05-20 00:31:46,811 main DEBUG createLoggers(={a.demo.of.log4j2, root})
2016-05-20 00:31:46,812 main DEBUG Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\demo\log4j2Demo\bin\log4j2.xml] initialized
2016-05-20 00:31:46,812 main DEBUG Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\demo\log4j2Demo\bin\log4j2.xml]
2016-05-20 00:31:46,813 main DEBUG Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\demo\log4j2Demo\bin\log4j2.xml] OK.
2016-05-20 00:31:46,813 main DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false-1
2016-05-20 00:31:46,813 main DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@6f539caf OK
2016-05-20 00:31:46,860 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=73d16e93
2016-05-20 00:31:46,862 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=73d16e93,component=StatusLogger
2016-05-20 00:31:46,864 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=73d16e93,component=ContextSelector
2016-05-20 00:31:46,865 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=73d16e93,component=Loggers,name=
2016-05-20 00:31:46,866 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=73d16e93,component=Loggers,name=a.demo.of.log4j2
2016-05-20 00:31:46,867 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=73d16e93,component=Appenders,name=console
2016-05-20 00:31:46,868 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=73d16e93,component=Appenders,name=file-log
2016-05-20 00:31:46,870 main DEBUG Reconfiguration complete for context[name=73d16e93] at URI C:\demo\log4j2Demo\bin\log4j2.xml (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@7722c3c3) with optional ClassLoader: null
2016-05-20 00:31:46,871 main DEBUG Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
2016-05-20 00:31:46,872 main DEBUG LoggerContext[name=73d16e93, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@7722c3c3] started OK.
[INFO ] 2016-05-20 00:31:46.878 [main] LogDemo - Hello world - info log
[WARN ] 2016-05-20 00:31:46.879 [main] LogDemo - Hello world - warn log
[ERROR] 2016-05-20 00:31:46.879 [main] LogDemo - Hello world - error log
2016-05-20 00:31:46,880 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Stopping LoggerContext[name=73d16e93, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@7722c3c3]
2016-05-20 00:31:46,880 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Stopping LoggerContext[name=73d16e93, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@7722c3c3]...
2016-05-20 00:31:46,882 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Shutting down RollingFileManager logs/log4j2demo-info.log
2016-05-20 00:31:46,882 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false
2016-05-20 00:31:46,882 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Stopped XmlConfiguration[location=C:\demo\log4j2Demo\bin\log4j2.xml] OK
2016-05-20 00:31:46,882 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Stopped LoggerContext[name=73d16e93, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@7722c3c3]...
```

**Windows directory listing showing file created but empty**

```
C:\demo\log4j2Demo\logs>dir
 Volume in drive C is dfsdf0694
 Volume Serial Number is asdffd

 Directory of C:\demo\log4j2Demo\logs

20/05/2016  12:45 AM    <DIR>          .
20/05/2016  12:45 AM    <DIR>          ..
20/05/2016  12:31 AM                 0 log4j2demo-info.log
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  263,832,457,216 bytes free
```

Comment: Try to provide an absolute file path instead of a relative one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not writing to your file because the Logger you are using to log is named log4j2Demo.LogDemo but the logger you have configured is named "a.demo.of.log4j2". Since the names don't match it will use the root logger, which you have configured to log to the console.

Comment: Here is the corrected snippet:  <Logger name="log4j2Demo.LogDemo" level="info" additivity="false">
   <appender-ref ref="file-log" level="info"/>
  </Logger>